# Kong vs Haproxy/F5 lb

Tags: haproxy, f5, kong

I am confusing about kong api gateway and Haproxy/F5 load balancer.

Will kong api gateway handle the load balancing also!

My scenario is, if i have 5 micro-services on kong. 2nd service consumes more load compare with others, the kong will manages load or not.

If not means what needs to be do?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Kong will **not** handle the load balancing. Even more, you will have to load balance Kong yourself as well.

There are plans to enable multiple upstream targets in one of the next versions, but right now you will have to load balance your microservice end points in addition to running them past Kong.

Kong is able to secure your microservices and do other nifty things, such as rate limiting and applying OAuth2.0 to them, but load balancing is not one of those things.

Comment: It means if 2nd service consumes more traffic then i need to add the another micro-services(same 2nd service ) to kong as different ip. Am i  correct!

Comment: Usually you would put your microservice behind a load balancer and point Kong to that.